# Group dataset based on labels

Tags: r, session, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset from a game app.
I want to cut my app dataset into sessions. A new session starts with an appstart or an appresume. It mostly ends with an appclose, but not always does.

The record structure looks like this:

```
appdata <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1), activity = c("appstart","appclose","appresume","run","appstart", "run", "run"),points = c(263,275,278,321, 322, 412, 498))

appdata
  userid  activity points
1      1  appstart    263
2      1  appclose    275
3      1 appresume    278
4      1       run    321
5      1  appstart    322
6      1       run    412
7      1       run    498
```

I want it to look like this:

```
appdata_new <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,1), session = c(1,2,3), mean_points = c(269, 299.5, 410.67))

appdata_new
  userid session mean_points
1      1       1      269.00
2      1       2      299.50
3      1       3      410.67
```

I've tried the following, based on a user's comment, but it was not working with my dataset:

```
appdata %>% group_by(userid, session = cumsum(lag(activity == "appstart", default = FALSE) | cumsum(lag(activity == "appresume", default = FALSE))) %>% summarise(mean_points = mean(points))
```

Comment: Try `appdata %>% group_by(userid, session = cumsum(lag(activity == "appclose", default = FALSE))) %>% summarise(mean_points = mean(points))`

Comment: I think the second `mean_points` should be different.  Can you please check

Comment: I was mistaken with the second mean_points, I have revised it now. @akrun: I tried the code on my dataset. It leads to wrong values in some cases, because in a few cases a new appstart comes without an appclose before. I need to add something like:
If in a session a second appstart appears before an appclose, then the session is closed. Can you help me out?